# Efficient comparison of two values several rows apart of one variable in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, comparison

I'm using R version 4.2.1 and I have a working solution for what I want to achieve (see below). Yet, it is extremely inefficient and would run for ~4 days to generate only one variable. Hence, I'm looking for a more efficient way to achieve my desired outcome.

**Data and problem description**

I have roughly 500,000 observations of 700ish firms across several time periods in a `data.table`. My data are uniquely identified by `firm_id`, `period`, and `destination`. I'm interested in **whether and when** these firms start operating at a specific destination. I know in which period a firm is operating at which destination. This information is provided by combining `destination` with another already existing variable called `destination_presence`. `destination_presence` is stored as `numeric`and provides information on whether a firm is operating at the destination stated by `destination`. `destination_presence` can be `NA`, `1`(= firm operates at the respective destination), or `0`(= firm does not operate at the respective destination). `destination` is a `factor` with 66 levels (e.g., "usa", "canada", ...) which is why for every `firm_id`-`period`-combination there are 66 observations in the data set.

My new variable `internationalization` can be `NA`, `1`(= firm started operations at respective destination in the current period), `0`(= firm did not start operation at respective destination in current period). Hence, `internationalization == 1` only happens at that time when a firm **starts** operations at a specific destination. Note, that this could occur more than one time as, e.g., a firm could start operations at destination D in period 2, leave destination D in period 4, and enter destination D again in period 9.

Here is a shortened example of the data:

**Data example**

```
#load packages
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(
  structure(list(
  firm_id = structure(as.factor(c(rep("f1", 18), rep("f2", 18), rep("f3", 18), rep("f4", 18)))),
  period = structure(as.factor(c(rep("3", 6), rep("5", 6), rep("6", 6), rep("1", 6), rep("2", 6), rep("3", 6), rep("0", 6), rep("1", 6), rep("2", 6), rep("7", 6), rep("8", 6), rep("9", 6)))), 
  min_period = structure(c(rep(3, 18), rep(1, 18), rep(0, 18), rep(7, 18))),
  destination = structure(as.factor(c("usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand", "usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand"))),
  destination_presence = structure(c(rep(NA, 6), 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, rep(NA, 6), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, rep(NA, 6)), class = "numeric")),
  .Names = c("firm_id", "period", "min_period", "destination", "destination_presence" ), row.names = c(NA, 5), class = "data.table"))
```

**Current approach**

```
# load packages
library(data.table) 

# order data by firm_id, period, and destination to make sure that all data are similarly ordered
dt <-
  dt[with(dt, order(firm_id, period, destination)), ]

# Step 1: fill first variable for minimum periods as in these cases there is no prior period with which to compare
dt[, internationalization := ifelse(
  period == min_period & # min_period is the minimum period for a specific firm
    destination_presence == 1,
  1,
  NA
)]

# show internationalization variable output
summary(as.factor(dt$internationalization))

# Step 2:
# there are 6 rows for every firm_id-period combination because there are 6 different levels in the factor variable destination (i.e., 6 different countries) in the example data set 
# hence, for the first 6 rows there are no prior ones to compare with. therefore, start in row 7
for (i in 7:nrow(dt)) {
print(i) # print i to know about progress of loop
dt$internationalization[i] <-
# a) if there is already a value in internationalization, keep this value (output from Step 1)
ifelse(
!is.na(dt$internationalization[i]),
dt$internationalization[i],
# b) if there is no information on the international operation destinations of a firm in the current period, insert NA in internationalization
ifelse(
is.na(dt$destination_presence[i]),
NA,
# c) if in prior period (i-6 because of 6 country levels per firm_id-period entry) there are no information on destination presence, treat observations as first internationalization
ifelse(
is.na(dt$destination_presence[i - 6]) & dt$firm_id[i] == dt$firm_id[i - 6],
dt$destination_presence[i],
# c) if in last period (i - 6) a specific firm was not operating at a specific destination (dt$destination_presence[i - 6] != 1) and is operating at this specific destination in the current period (dt$destination_presence[i] == 1), set internationalization == 1
ifelse(
(dt$destination_presence[i] == 1) & (dt$destination_presence[i - 6] != 1) & (dt$firm_id[i] == dt$firm_id[i - 6]),
1,
0
)
)
)
)
}
```

**Desired outcome**

This should match outcome from the approach described above.

```
# desired outcome
desired_dt <- as.data.table(
  structure(list(
    firm_id = structure(as.factor(c(rep("f1", 18), rep("f2", 18), rep("f3", 18), rep("f4", 18)))),
    period = structure(as.factor(c(rep("3", 6), rep("5", 6), rep("6", 6), rep("1", 6), rep("2", 6), rep("3", 6), rep("0", 6), rep("1", 6), rep("2", 6), rep("7", 6), rep("8", 6), rep("9", 6)))), 
    min_period = structure(c(rep(3, 18), rep(1, 18), rep(0, 18), rep(7, 18))),
    destination = structure(as.factor(c("usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand", "usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand","usa", "chile", "austria", "kenya", "china", "new zealand"))),
    destination_presence = structure(c(rep(NA, 6), 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, rep(NA, 6), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, rep(NA, 6)), class = "numeric"),
    internationalization = structure(c(rep(NA, 6), 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, rep(NA, 6), rep(0, 5), 1, rep(0,6), 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, rep(NA, 6)))),            
    .Names = c("firm_id", "period", "min_period", "destination", "destination_presence", "internationalization"), row.names = c(NA, 6), class = "data.table"))
```

Looking forward to your suggestions on how to make the code more efficient!

Comment: I didn't think that data.table functions had a notion of row ordering. Do you have a link to documentation that corrects my aging notions on that point?

Comment: Are you referring to this chunk of code ``dt <-  dt[with(dt, order(firm_id, period, destination)), ]``? This is not data.table specific and I found it on stackoverflow when still working on another issue a couple of months ago. I just also tried to use ``setkey()`` to also set the identifiers for the dataset but then the for-loop actually produced a wrong output. I'm not sure whether this answers your comment. I'll look for the stackoverflow post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a single chained command using `data.table`'s `setorder` and `shift` functions. It will be very fast.

```
setorder(dt, firm_id, destination, period)[, internationalization := destination_presence*(firm_id != shift(firm_id, 1, "") | destination != shift(destination, 1, "") | !pmax(0, shift(destination_presence), na.rm = TRUE))]
```

Notice that `min_period` is not used.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for this solution. It's really fast.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edited to include @jblood94 code in the performaces below

The `for` loop is the culprit for slowing your code here. An `tidyverse` alternative option would help speed the process.

#### Code

---

```
dt= as.data.frame(dt) #transform your data into a data frame
dt$id = 1:nrow(dt) # Add a unique row id to select them later
dt$period = as.numeric(dt$period) # Change the factor into numeric

#Create an intermediate dataframe only with the data of interest 
temp = dt %>% filter(destination_presence == 1) %>% 
  group_by(firm_id, destination) %>% 
  mutate(b = ifelse(lag(period)==period-1, 0, 1), #if period are consecutive transform to 0
         int = ifelse(is.na(b)|b==1, 1, 0))%>% #the final internationalization variable to be added in the original data frame
  select(-b) #remove the useless column

dt$inter = dt$destination_presence # Create the internationalization column based on the destination
dt[temp$id, "inter"] = temp$int # Transfer the column for the identified rows above

dt
    firm_id period min_period destination destination_presence internationalization
 1:      f1      3          3     austria                   NA                   NA
 2:      f1      5          3     austria                    0                    0
 3:      f1      6          3     austria                    0                    0
 4:      f1      3          3       chile                   NA                   NA
 5:      f1      5          3       chile                    0                    0
 6:      f1      6          3       chile                    0                    0
 7:      f1      3          3       china                   NA                   NA
 8:      f1      5          3       china                    0                    0
 9:      f1      6          3       china                    0                    0
10:      f1      3          3       kenya                   NA                   NA
11:      f1      5          3       kenya                    1                    1
12:      f1      6          3       kenya                    1                    0
13:      f1      3          3 new zealand                   NA                   NA
14:      f1      5          3 new zealand                    1                    1
15:      f1      6          3 new zealand                    1                    0
16:      f1      3          3         usa                   NA                   NA
17:      f1      5          3         usa                    0                    0
```

#### Performance

---

Edited: Code from @jblood94 added as `fast_function`

I warped up your code as `old_function` and the code abode as `new_function`. Your code is actually faster to run on the example data frame you provided. However when the number of row is increase the `new_function` is far much effective.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this alternative and shedding some light into the different performance outcomes of the approaches!